# Microsoft Test Manager tool

Tags: automated-testing, mstest, mtm

I really need help on Microsoft Test Manager tool. I have worked on selenium with java tool and MTM is very difficult for me understand and learn. To replay the recorded test in MTM, it always fail does not open the application url. Is there any way we can export the recorded MTM test to C++ as we used to do in Selenium IDE.

Also, is there any online help or tutorial for creating MTM test script and run it from C++, same as we used to do in selenium with Java.

I also want to ask question that MTM required human efforts to run script, I found that while recording script we need to write the test case manually and than while recording we need to status the steps with pass/fail. Does same process is followed while playing recorded steps? As of now, when i play the steps it always fail and does not execute

I would appreciate your response and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can export a test recorded with MTM to a Coded UI test and that is either C# or VB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Test Manager is primarily a tool for managing manual tests. The MTM test recordings can be exported to CodedUI then modified in Visual Studio, but they are not automated tests and should not be treated as such.

If you have Microsoft Team Foundation Server configured to manage test environment virtual systems, you can configure MTM to run automated tests (I've never done this myself). In Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate (If you have MTM, you should have the Premium license) you can associate an MTM test case with CodedUI tests or MS unit tests. Once you've done this and set up the TFS lab environment, you can run your automated tests via MTM.

If you have to use MTM to manage your automated tests, I'd suggest one of two options:

- exporting MTM tests to CodedUI tests in C# (the language is kind of a hybrid between Java and C++, so should not be difficult for you to work with). With this option you could still run the tests via MTM if you have the correct environment configuration.
- build your tests using Selenium in the language you prefer, and work with the TFS API to post your test results to the corresponding tests in MTM (this option is rather more complicated - the TFS API is not for the faint-hearted). With this option, your automation will live in its own ecosystem, but the test results will automagically be available in MTM.

Either way, it's not as easy as it should be, something I hope Microsoft is going to address in future versions.

Comment: Thanks Kate for your valuable reply. I would appreciate if you could send link for tutorial or document where I can get the step by step information about exporting MTM test to COdedUI. Also, just want to know that is there any tool I have install to use CodedUI in my VS I do not see CodedUI under Test menu can you pls help me on this.

Comment: @Dani - start with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx - this list gives you practically everything you need for CodedUI. If you have VS premium or ultimate, you can create a CodedUI project - once you do that, everything on the Test menu is the same as for a unit test project.

Comment: Thanks Kate, your reply is highly respected and appreciated... :)

Comment: Hey, @KatePaulk, it's me from another question about statring a job in MS ecosystem. You mentioned *Selenium in the language you prefer* -- the part of our project that needs automatisation the most urgently is web-interface. So can you advise some argument I could tell my bosses, why it would be easy for me and for my future collegues (especially since they probably would came from manual testing and not technically educated) if we start automating web-GUI testing in some script language and not in Visual Studio?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't recommend it - it would be much harder for you because you would need to write a custom interface to TFS before you could link your tests to test cases written in MTM. I'd suggest you search "TFS API" and look at the information there before making any decisions.